# Custom section Iphone

Tags: uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a table View and in the very start I have one section and one cell. There is the button on the section where i can add more cell. That is fine. But on my Navigation Controller bar I have an other button item (for adding more section). Section are adding but the no of cell are remain same in each section. I want this 
section A  = 6 cell
section B = 2 cell and so on.
we can add more section and cell. How can i managed the no of cell in each section repeatedly.
My problem is my each section contain same no of cell.

```
- (IBAction)addsection:(id)sender {
    section +=1;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}



- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

   // sectionDictionary = @{// Section Array with its object Array Key value};

    section = 1;
    rowS = 1;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return section;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{   NSString *name  = @"name";

    return name;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return rowS;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CreateProblemSolutionTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.problemLabel.text = @"Problem";
    cell.problemDetailsLabel.text = @"some problem here";
    cell.solutionLabel.text = @"Solution";
    cell.solutionDetails.text = @"Solution details";
    return cell;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // create the parent view that will hold header Label
    UIView* customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.0, 0.0, 10.0, 44.0)];


    [customView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

    UIButton *headerbutton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 0, 100, 20)];
    [headerbutton setTitle:@"press me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [headerbutton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [headerbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(addingRows) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [customView addSubview:headerbutton];

    UILabel *sectionName = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 150, 20)];
    [sectionName setText:@"Section Name"];
    [sectionName setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [customView addSubview:sectionName];

    return customView;
}


-(void)addingRows
{
    rowS +=1;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Show us the code you have tried, and what the problem is with it... http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Nonono, you need to **edit** your question, and add that. Click on "edit" at the bottom of question.